# problem including gtk/gtk.h file not found windows 10 Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gtk3, file-not-found

There seems to be a problem floating around for some people using VSCode.  I have confirmed the installation of GTK with the terminal window and everything went well.

I wrote a quick program in C to read an address and print it back.  It compiles and runs (**without the "#include <gtk.gtk.h">**) creating the .exe file so I can confirm VScode is installed correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main()
{

    int var = 20; /* variable declaration*/
    int *ip;      /* pointer variable declaration */

    ip = &var; /* store the address of var in pointer variable */

    printf("Address of var variable:  %x\n", &var);

    /* address stored in the pointer variable */
    printf("Address stored in ip the pointer variable: %x\n", ip);

    /* access the variable the *ip variable points to */
    printf("Value of *ip variable: %d\n", *ip);

    return 0;
}
```

When I add the #include <gtk/gtk.h>  statement, I get the error that it cannot be found.   >#include errors detected. Please update your includePath.<

I used the command "pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0" in a terminal to create the path in c-cpp.json file

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin",
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/gtk-3.0", 
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/pango-1.0", 
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/include", 
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/glib-2.0", 
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/glib-2.0/include", 
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/harfbuzz", 
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/freetype2",
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/libpng16", 
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/fribidi", 
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/cairo", 
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/lzo", 
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/pixman-1", 
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0", 
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/atk-1.0",
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib"
            ],
            

            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

the directory gtk is in the C:/msys64/mingw64/include/gtk-3.0 directory and the gtk.h file is in the gtk directory. Intellisense even prompted for the directory and file.